# Transferring Claims From MVC5 to API 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

Currently, we have authentication set up for our MVC app using federated authentication via the Identity Server. This works great.

Now, we have a backend which uses API 2 and is not in the same project nor even on the same server. Is there a way we can transfer the claims from the MVC app to the Web API layer?

Thanks,
Derek